# Question single-handedly put on hold as too broad within two minutes of posting

Tags: discussion, support, reopen-closed, on-hold

<sup>*Have we come to a state where moderation overtakes **and** overrules answering questions? Has the purpose of Stack Exchange shifted from being a "good answer provider" to being a "good question filter"?*</sup>

My question:

> https://stackoverflow.com/q/27895571/1134080

was closed and put on hold as too broad by [a single moderator with 26.5K rep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber) **within two minutes** of posting it.

Despite being given the following comment:

> I am asking this question **precisely because** it's too broad. I had been struggling to pinpoint what the real problem is for a week now, and has come up with nothing. But I am not very well-versed with the technologies used, hence I am seeking for some tips and pointers from users here who may be more experienced. *Please be kind enough to take it off hold!*

and the following edit summary:

> Please see comment and reopen. The question is understandably broad by nature, and cannot be narrowed down reasonably, but I have mentioned my main aim here as a focus point.

there has been **no response** so far regarding the reopening of the question.

Understandably the question is by its very nature, quite broad and I don't deny it. But if I could narrow down the problem to something more specific, **I would not even be posting the question in the first place.**

The reason for my question is clear. I have a problem. I have looked for solutions, and have not found any. So I am asking the question. Getting it closed as too broad is extremely unhelpful and as such eroding the value of this site. Please consider there *may be* users now or in the future who may want to post an answer to the question, but cannot because it has been put on hold.

Comment: [+1](http://www.keepcalmstudio.com/_gallery/300/kcs_670a65c8.png)

Comment: This site has a very clear scope which doesn't include questions like this one. Yes, it sucks for you that your question doesn't fit into what Stack Overflow is about, but that's not a good enough reason to reopen it.

Comment: I'm not very well-versed with those technologies either, so I ignored the question as outside my experience. I do know, however, that such intermittent bugs can be very hard to pin down with access to the environment, logs, source code, debugger etc.  The looping appears to be within your servlet, and you have a weeks' worth of debugging experience and results that you should not and could not post in an SO question.  I do hope that someone has seen this problem before and just knows the answer straight off, but the chances of that seem slim.  What would you have us do that you cannot?

Comment: "I am asking this question precisely because it's too broad" megaultrafacepalm

Comment: In addition to what @MartinJames says above, note that if people have debugging advice, *they can still post it*. From that, you may get enough information for a better question, or find your solution.

Comment: To your edit, from day 1, the means by which SO has been a good answer provider has been by being a good question filter.  Bad questions result in bad answers, so by filtering out the bad questions, you get much better answers.  Nothing about this policy is in any way new.  There is no magic button that you can press or formula that you can use to just get great answers from all questions, regardless of how bad they are.

Answer (score 32):

I am an elected community moderator; that gives me the ability to put questions on-hold unilaterally. The community can still reopen it. Posts can be flagged for another moderator to review, as well; though the community can usually act more quickly.

In this case, two minutes was more than enough to reach the conclusion I reached.

Not sure why you think I owed you a response to what amounted to, "yes; the question is too broad; that's why I posted it"... I'm not sure what else to say; it's too broad. You not only admit that, but you say that's exactly why you posted it.

It seems that perhaps you just don't care about the fact that it's not a good fit for the site?

Comment: What can one do when it's not possible to narrow down the question? Isn't the site also about trying to solve problems encountered? At least consider reopening it to give it a chance...

Comment: @ADTC This site is about trying to solve problems that fall within its scope. In the same way that questions about non-programming topics aren't in scope, overly broad questions are equally disallowed. If it's not possible to narrow it down anymore, then you just need to take it somewhere else, where they accept questions of this nature.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Would the question fall in the scope of ServerFault? If yes, can a moderator move the question there and reopen it?

Comment: @ADTC: no, broad questions do not fit the model of Q&A sites. This is not about the topic here.

Comment: @ADTC note that if you find a way to narrow the scope of your question edit it, it will go in the reopen queue automatically.